# Exporting Linkedin Learning Video source to .txt file

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am very new to python, and programming in general.

I am trying to scrape a LinkedIn Learning web page to locate the full file path for the video on the page.

Ideally, I would like the script to be able to accept a course url and cycle through each video in the course, to pull the video file path from each video page within the course.

From reviewing the source, I found the area I am interested in is as follows:

`<div> data-vjs-player etc etc </div>`

Within this div, there is a video element. Within this element, is a src callout which contains the video link I am looking for, example as follows:

`<video id="vjs_video_3_html5_api" class="vjs-tech" preload="auto" poster="https://media-exp1.licdn.com/dms/image/C4E0DAQEEM3rME8wwFw/learning-public-crop_675_1200/0?e=1595858400&amp;v=beta&amp;t=V5KkqHuGqUTliAMbL7oUBXeEWcrfBDdi4QrZbyGyAWE" src="https://files3.lynda.com/secure/courses/614299/VBR_MP4h264_main_HD720/614299_00_02_XR15_exfiles.mp4?0pnG4-hMq6_WSlXmJvkGQa6ubLk5EIuE8SG-D0jd9RJOztR5jY8wmlBcsWjHLzBK22z6DydJXGoV8njYeJ_A-dMb6BIZrtkZdUq20t2tD6hxhdNKeWVvik7aOfN3Oyv78_wqePFK1rGmujQnzbCYudW9r0Oyl54EcFQhUqUFnGpkVqHLgQ_Gndo"></video>`

I attempted to utilize the following code as a basis, following a BeautifulSoup tutorial to parse the website link for the src callout:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from lxml import html

import requests

URL = 'https://www.linkedin.com/learning/python-essential-training-2/about-python-3?u=2154233'
page = requests.get(URL)

soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html5lib')

results = soup.find(id="vjs_video_3_html5_api")
print(results.prettify())
```

However, it is at this point I have come to a standstill, as I do not understand where to go here, despite researching this to the best of my abilities at this current time.

I really would appreciate any help or guidance that you may be able to provide on this.

Thank you all in advance.

Answer (score 0):

When you look at source HTML (for example `print(soup)`), you will see that the class of `<video>` tag is different.

You can extract the video url with this example:

```
import json
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


url = 'https://www.linkedin.com/learning/python-essential-training-2/about-python-3?u=2154233'
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, 'html.parser')
data = json.loads(soup.video['data-sources'])
print(data[0]['src'])
```

Prints:

```
https://files3.lynda.com/secure/courses/614299/VBR_MP4h264_main_SD/614299_00_03_XR30_aboutpy.mp4?jNwDi0oWUMSPUqh0j6w7yy2IDyBgoGZEeY9Tj2TKVmZmpSMisIoXxG9K1BbRELSP_pM9ySZOFiOq6TzNFvxhEWoGujEGQYT7TfRhuXGwJyGffd5uWTdYBCoc65J-YJuvdg7xijnaDwVjFuUKSAJZxqvYyq8f5nOZrE0Mgckk-1XANfovQ8E
```